# SQL SERVER 2008 - Returning a portion of text using SUBSTRING AND CHARINDEX. Need to return all text UNTIL a specific char

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have a column called 'response' that contains lots of data about a person.

I'd like to only return the info after a specific string

But, using the method below I sometimes (when people have <100 IQ) get the | that comes directly after the required number..

I'd like any characters after the'PersonIQ=' but only before the pipe.

I'm not sure of the best way to achieve this.

Query speed is a concern and my idea of nested CASE is likely not the best solution.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks

```
substring(response,(charindex('PersonIQ=',response)+9),3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's always a pipe, you could do this:

```
substring(stuff(reponse,1,charindex('PersonIQ=',reponse)-1,''),1,charindex('|',stuff(reponse,1,charindex('PersonIQ=',reponse)-1,''))-1)
```

Or, you could convert your string to xml and reference PersonIQ directly, e.g.:

```
--assuming your string looks something like this..
declare @s varchar(max) = 'asdaf=xxx|PersonIQ=100|xxx=yyy'

select convert(xml, '<x ' + replace(replace(@s, '=', '='''), '|', ''' ') + '''/>').value('(/x/@PersonIQ)[1]','int')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion:

```
declare @s varchar(200) = 'aaa=bbb|cc=d|PersonIQ=99|e=f|1=2'
declare @iq varchar(10) = 'PersonIQ='
declare @pipe varchar(1) = '|'

select substring(@s, 
        charindex(@iq, @s) + len(@iq), 
        charindex(@pipe, @s, charindex(@iq, @s)) - (charindex(@iq, @s) + len(@iq)) 
        )
```

Instead of the `3` in your formula you should calculate the space between @iq and @pipe with this last part of the formula `charindex(@pipe, @s, charindex(@iq, @s)) - (charindex(@iq, @s) + len(@iq))`, which gets the first @pipe index after @iq, and then substructs the index of the IQ value.